# I want to take latest of project but when we click on solution of project means root in solution explore then there is no Update latest option

Tags: c#

Example is given as below first one is right:
[image: This image display the Update latest option.]

[image: Second is not display Update option.]

Comment: When we going for take latest and click on Solution of project then Update latest option is not displaying some time before it worked.

Comment: you can see both the images click on link above.

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of Tortoise SVN name as:
1. TortoiseSVN-1.9.2.26806-x64-svn-1.9.2 and 
2. AnkhSvn-2.5.12703.